# VS Code files don't sync up to debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

From my testing I've noticed attaching my debugger (js) resolves the file to an absolute path but when I open the file through the explorer it opens a relative path via the working directory.

The problem being that they are treated as different files and if I set a breakpoint in a file opened through explorer it is grayed out but if I open the file via f1 through the absolute path I am able to set breakpoints.

It's super annoying having multiple identical files open, what am I missing here? I've toyed with many a setting and no luck!

Comment: What version of VS code and what environment are you running? Operating system?

Comment: windows 10 - vscode v.1.27.2 attempting to attach to a gulp process. It doesn't matter if attach to port or attach by picking process id, the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is your  workspace path  under a symbolic link in a U*x?

VS Code apparently dereferences symbolic links to give Node a path that it can work with, to support breakpoints.

VS Code *also* shows the file at the correctly referenced path in the workspace folder as defined (under the symbolic link).

(See this SO  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788044) and this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78443).)