# Why are Nodejs breakpoints in VS Code disabled depending on whether the full path appears in the tab title?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

A breakpoint in my Mocha test works when set on the exact same line in one VS Code tab but not in another.

The difference: If  the full path appears in the tab, then  breakpoints work. (Second item in screenshot.)

[image: Two different access paths]

But if the filename, without path,  appears in the tab header, then  breakpoints all become Unverified (gray) during execution.

Repro steps:

- If you open files from the  Explorer view, the bug occurs.
- If you open files using CTRL-P, as in the screenshot, then both
  variants are usually available, and choosing the one with/without
  path gives the different behaviors.

How can I avoid this without continually checking which path variant is appearing?

([Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78443) is a GitHub ticket that I opened.)

Comment: No repro steps, so hard to be sure.  The debugger engine requires a file on disk, the kind you open with Ctrl+P.  The first one doesn't look like it was saved yet.

Comment: See repro steps above. Both variations of file-tab get saved to disk (Autosave is enabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer (figured out on the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78443)):

My workspace path was under a symbolic link (Ubuntu).

VS Code apparently dereferences symbolic links to  give  Node a path that it can work with, to support breakpoints.

VS Code *also* shows the file at the correctly referenced path in my workspace folder as I defined it (under the symbolic link).

Comment: Wow. That would indeed be a surprise for people in *nix world